# Swift 3.0 - How to build Sourcekit and Sourcekitten in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, swift, build, swift3, sourcekit

What are the steps in building Sourcekit and Sourcekitten for the stable release version of Swift 3.0? Thanks in advance.

Note: Dependencies and other tools for building are already installed as per https://github.com/apple/swift

Answer (score 0):

This is duplicate to [Building Swift SourceKit on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941523/building-swift-sourcekit-on-linux)

Updated Nov.24, 2016.

### Build Sourcekit

The official branch of swift may still have the issue https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1676. But Norio Nomura maintained a docker building environment here https://github.com/norio-nomura/docker-sourcekit-builder/

If you don't want to build it yourself, just download the package with sourcekit https://github.com/norio-nomura/docker-sourcekit-builder/releases

You may have to put *libsourcekitdInProc.so* under lib directory of this package into your lib path, or the lib directory into your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

### Build SourceKitten

SourceKitten has Linux support now. Download the [git source code](https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten) and use `swift build`.

Comment: For sourcekit, this is now builds on Linux. For sourcekitten, as per its developer they are currently working on it for Linux... Let's leave this question open probably I will answer my own question once sourcekitten is ready for Linux.