# How to use SourceKit python bindings?

Tags: swift, sourcekit

Sorry for such broad question, but after some attempts I'm not sure how to use python bindings. I tried to just import "request.py" or "capi.py" but all I got were errors. After adding missing libraries to my search path, I ended with missing symbol "_dispatch queue_attr_concurrent" (which suggest wrong library version?).

My question isn't about that particular error, but rather correct way of interacting with python bindings (and SourceKit itself). I have tried to use precompiled version, and compile it myself (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40033117/1117854), but result was all the same.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Or maybe someone with similar experience succeed and have some tips? It's not well documented and I'll probably find solution sooner or later, but I believe I'm not the only one who felt lost after first contact with SourceKit.